# addEventListener won't work because of null

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

All I'm trying to do is have the user click the button, and when that event occurs I want an image to display within a div. I inspected the element, and it says that tableButton is undefined, but I defined it right before the addEventListener. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I'm new to javascript.

```
function openTable() {
    var code = "<img src='PeriodicTableOfElements.png'>";
    var periodic = document.getElementById("Periodic");
    periodic.innerHTML = code;
}

var tableButton = document.getElementById("openTable");
tableButton.addEventListener("click", openTable, false);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `document.getElementById("openTable")` actually resolves to a DOM node?

Comment: `I defined it right before`   only if that node exists, if it doesn't will return `undefined`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it exists... I have a div with an ID of openTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure to wrap it in `window.onload`, elements can't exist if the window hasn't loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
  function openTable() {
      var code = "<img src='PeriodicTableOfElements.png'>";
      var periodic = document.getElementById("Periodic");
      periodic.innerHTML = code;
  }

  var tableButton = document.getElementById("openTable");
  tableButton.addEventListener("click", openTable, false);
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderManzano Be sure to click the green checkmark if this solved your issue.  This is how you show your appreciation on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you this fixed it! However, can you explain the onload thing? I thought the elements will load once I hit refresh because I see the div button load.

Comment: You can perform JavaScript before the website is done loading.  If the HTML file is not done loading yet, you can't select elements properly.

Comment: So if an element loads before the window has loaded, the element will be undefined? Therefore, I have to use onload to make sure the element is defined? Sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: If you use `document` to select elements before the window has loaded, it's undefined because the window is what contains all the HTML.  If the window hasn't finished loading, there is no HTML to select.  And it's alright.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense! Thank you, again! :)